# What is the brown cardboard covering coffee cups called in English?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary, british-english, image-identification

I recently got into an awkward situation when I wasn't able to ask for a 'warmth protector thingy' in Starbucks, and wasn't accurately able to describe it, so could someone tell me what you would call the brown paper thing covering the plastic cup of coffee? I struggle to find it anywhere because it's hard to describe, hence why the title is badly phrased. 
edit: would zarf be socially acceptable to use in a casual environment?

[image: What is the brown cover called?]

Comment: So, next time you enter a Starbucks' are you going to ask for a coffee condom? Good luck with that and seeing the facial expression of the  woman server when she asks "Say, what?" "I beg your pardon?" and "I'm sorry would you repeat that, please?" especially in this day and age of political correctness. Seriously, try out both answers next time you order a coffee on the go, "coffee condom" and "java jacket" and tell us if everything went smoothly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've certainly heard these corrugated cup-coverings casually called ***coffee condoms*** by college kids around campus (with the occasional “ribbed for her pleasure” snickers).

As might be expected of a coinage like this, [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Coffee%20Condom) offers the most baldfaced definition of this bit of street slang:

> ## *Coffee Condom*
>
> The name for the sleeve that goes around your handle-less paper coffee cup to insulate the drinker's hands from hot coffee.
>
> Similar to how a latex condom is designed to protect you from sexually transmitted diseases the "coffee condom" is designed to protect your hand from the hot cup of coffee.

## Java Jacket

*Smithsonian Magazine* from 2013-08-13 had an article on [“How the Coffee Cup Sleeve Was Invented”](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/arts-culture/how-the-coffee-cup-sleeve-was-invented-119479/) containing a more detailed history of this device, including this small bit:

> Jay Sorensen invented the **Java Jacket** in 1991 as a solution to a common problem—hot coffee burns fingers. The idea emerged in 1989 when he was pulling out of a coffee shop drive-through on the way to his daughter’s school and a coffee spill burned his fingers, forcing him to release a scalding cup of coffee onto his lap. At the time, he was struggling as a realtor in the years since closing his family-owned service station in Portland, Oregon. While the coffee accident was unfortunate, it gave him the germ of an innovative idea: there had to be a better way to drink coffee on the go.

Sorensen ended up patenting his Java Jacket idea, and he sells a billion (B-I-L-L-I-O-N) of these a year. But the one you get at Starbucks is ever so lightly different enough that they got their own patent after Sorenson got his. An earlier patent for such a device was granted back in 1964:

[image: Picture of earlier patent from the USPTO]

And there have been many others besides that one. The *Smithsonian* article also mentions one called a *portable coaster* back in 1947.

Comment: Tsk, tsk… the UD definition was posted in 2013 and has received an impressive 7 thumbs up since then.

Answer (score 87):

It is called a "sleeve." Although the primary meaning refers to that part of clothing which covers the wearer's arms in part or in whole, by analogy it has come to mean a tightly fitting, tubular protective covering. See [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sleeve) for a more detailed definition.

Comment: I've tried to see, but you've said sleeves are for clothing. I've tried to find a 'coffee sleeve' but it doesn't seem to make sense as I can't find anything regarding this. Is there a more common / known way that everyone uses?

Comment: American here: I would call it a sleeve as well. I can't think of a more proper name at the moment.

Comment: Tyler, they are called **coffee cup sleeves**. Not coffee sleeves.

Comment: Sleeve is usual in both UK and USA. See this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee_cup_sleeve. Apparently a "clutch" is an alternative term, but I've never heard that used.

Comment: Sleeve is also the term of choice in Canada.

Comment: "cardboard sleeve" is probably what I'd say.

Comment: Can confirm.  Wife is addicted to starbucks, and I always have to ask for a "Sleeve" in the drive through and have never had any confusion.

Comment: **Heat** sleeve. A sleeve can also refer to a half-pint of beer (or any drink).

Comment: @DevNull What dialect is that in? It's not a term I've ever heard of before.

Comment: @DevNull I'm pretty sure you can't order a "sleeve of coffee" at a Starbucks (the coffee shop explicitly referenced in OP's question). In fact I'd bet that asking for such, if anything, would get you the desired cardboard sleeve. Having said that, "cardboard sleeve" is wholly unambiguous, and should also help a clueless server figure out what sort of "sleeve" the customer is asking for.

Comment: @IMSoP Seems to be known amongst Canadians and Kiwis.

Comment: Yup - I'd probably forget what it was, and ask for a "warmth protector thingy", but otherwise "sleeve" is as good as it gets. Got to remember, these things have only been around for the past couple of decades for most people. In 1974 Starbucks only had 2 stores. I remember that, as I was living in Seattle that year. All this stuff only got introduced to most of the US in the 90's, I think.

Comment: When I was in college, I worked during the summer in a parts warehouse for a manufacturer of heavy machinery. There were many types of devices that were protective in some way or other, bearings, shims, sleeves, etc. Sleeve" as a tubular protective envelope is not restricted to paper coffee cups.

Answer (score 24):

A historic term for a coffee cup sleeve would be **[zarf](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/zarf)** -- it traditionally refers to nondisposable Turkish metal sleeves but has also been used to refer to the disposable paper ones.

(Disclaimer: I've only once heard a sleeve actually being referred to as a zarf at a coffeeshop, and it was a "hey did you know" kind of thing from the barista)

Comment: So a zarf is a metal sleeve intended to protect your hand from the hot beverage inside the cup?  ...wouldn't that sleeve also heat up with the cup?

Comment: "Zarf" is a new word for me - thanks for sharing! A search for ["zarf coffee" images](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=zarf+coffee&d=1&bext=wcp&atb=v56-7_a&iax=images&ia=images) was very enlightening!

Comment: @BruceWayne Looking at [images of zarfs](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=zarf+coffee), I'm not sure how the goblet-shaped ones work, but others provide a handle, which would stay cool for the same reasons the handle on a ceramic mug stays cool.

Comment: While this is interesting as a novelty term, the coffee cup sleeve is not a paper version of a traditional zarf; it has an [independent history](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/arts-culture/how-the-coffee-cup-sleeve-was-invented-119479/).

Comment: @choster While the invention of the "Java Jacket" is interesting, that doesn't mean that folks don't call them "zarfs" today. The image search for zarf turns up as many other types of sleeves as it does traditional zarfs, and multiple sources have definitions that include the disposable version (or don't exclude it). It may be a recent evolution brought on by Starbuck's proclivity for using "novelty" terms. Check out this [search on Etsy for zarf](https://www.etsy.com/market/coffee_zarf)

Comment: @ColleenV I would say it's pretty uncommon, at least in the US, except among people who enjoy being too clever by half. The larger point is that if someone is a language learner, suggesting they use a word to which the average person will return only a blank stare will hardly result in a salutary experience for them. On EL&U I would have upvoted this answer.

Comment: @choster Well the answer does mention how uncommon it is, and I think it's better to know too many words for something than not enough ;) The more common answer of "sleeve" is obviously the community's choice, so I don't see much harm in offering an alternative.

Comment: If it wasn't for the disclaimer about how uncommon the word is, I would probably have downvoted as offering bad advice. But this is a fair cop.

Comment: A "zarf" historically is not a sleeve, it is an outer cup with a bottom. Detailed 1871 drawings on page 174 here: https://books.google.com/books?id=xTUPAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA174&dq=%22zarf%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjewYLM0oTYAhUhhuAKHXY6AG8Q6AEINDAC#v=onepage&q=%22zarf%22&f=false

Comment: @Tyler Click on his link and read definition 2,a "A tubular part... designed to fit over another part." In this case that would be the card board piece fitting over the cup.

Comment: For interest, the "tea glass holder" (common in Russia) is described here, it's pronounced "pod-stah-cahn-neek: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Podstakannik

Comment: I always thought that the point of a zarf was to provide an actual handle.  When I was a kid, there was a common kind of disposable coffee cup consisting of an inverted cone made from thin polystyrene.  The cup could not stand on its own and would be too hot to hold when filled with hot coffee, so it was invariably served in a reusable zarf made of injected polyethylene.  It was useful for venues that served coffee, but only had cleaning facilities sufficient to rinse off the zarfs but not to process mugs that had contact with people's mouths.

Answer (score 4):

It is called "**Coffee cup sleeve**", and it is known also in the following names:

> [coffee **sleeves**](https://www.google.com.ua/search?biw=1366&bih=662&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=wCc1WuqAA-bP6ASg_5v4BQ&q=CUP%20sleeves&oq=CUP%20sleeves&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l7j0i5i30k1l3.131800.134401.0.134538.11.9.0.2.2.0.222.949.7j1j1.9.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.10.877...0i67k1.0.FW1uz37JUBM)
>
> [**Grip** cup sleeves](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=Grip%20Cup%20Sleeve&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVr9u_2Y7YAhVnD5oKHSuSBOQQ_AUICigB&biw=1366&bih=662)
>
> [Coffee **clutches**](https://www.google.com.ua/search?biw=1366&bih=662&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=Tig1WobYFePB6QSGzqwQ&q=coffee%20clutches&oq=coffee%20clutches&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i24k1.31389.31389.0.31556.1.1.0.0.0.0.103.103.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.101....0.hOxwoTp9Ia4)
>
> [Coffee **cozies**](https://www.google.com.ua/search?biw=1366&bih=662&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=ESg1WtGMHeHE6QSd14SYDw&q=coffee%20**cozies&oq=coffee%20**cozies&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i30k1l2j0i5i30k1j0i8i30k1.12838.12838.0.13074.1.1.0.0.0.0.144.144.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.142....0.gTbRSu76r5s) (refers mainly to those that they're for multiple use)
>
> [Hot cup **jackets**](https://www.google.com.ua/search?biw=1366&bih=662&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=7ig1WoW7McXP6ATA5Q4&q=hot%20cup%20jackets&oq=hot%20cup%20jackets&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3774.4738.0.5060.4.3.1.0.0.0.151.309.2j1.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.KhxZby8yJfU)
>
> [Paper **zarfs**](https://www.google.com.ua/search?biw=1366&bih=662&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=9Sg1WuDkJYXM6ATXhK6YDQ&q=paper%20zarfs&oq=paper%20zarfs&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0.18659.18659.0.18955.1.1.0.0.0.0.84.84.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.83....0.y28ggZKOrKI)
>
> [Coffee **collars**](https://www.google.com.ua/search?biw=1366&bih=662&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=CSk1WubTGoGL6ATZmoToBQ&q=coffee%20collars&oq=coffee%20collars&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0.41091.41091.0.41223.1.1.0.0.0.0.90.90.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.89....0.tu6Q9au2lu8)
>
> [Hot cup **holders**](https://www.google.com.ua/search?biw=1366&bih=662&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=iCk1WsXQAqjw6ATVk4WgCw&q=%22hot%20cup%20holders%22&oq=%22hot%20cup%20holders%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i8i30k1l3.28605.30294.0.30454.2.2.0.0.0.0.84.162.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.161....0.TxxgIxcO2ys#imgrc=jQzAWSpsbxYJLM:)

([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee_cup_sleeve))

Searching these names on internet stores prove that the most of them are in use in the market. By clicking on the links you will see the results in Google images, and there you will find a lot stores which use these names.

Comment: I've heard them called coffee collars before.

Answer (score 2):

On the the more technically accurate side, the complete term would be **coffee cup sleeve**. It's surprising that no one here actually mentioned that it even has got its own Wikipedia page. Follow [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee_cup_sleeve) for the details.

Comment: Yes, the Wikipedia link was mentioned and posted two days ago in the [comments](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/149863/what-is-the-brown-cardboard-covering-coffee-cups-called-in-english#comment303580_149864) below Jeff Morrow's answer.

Answer (score 1):

A “warmth protector thingy” can also be called an `insulator`, but `sleeve`, `coffee sleeve`, or even `cardboard sleeve` are all acceptable.  `Coffee condom` should be used very selectively.